# RichTextBox in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, richtextbox

I have a question about Rich Text Box in VS2010.

I have RTB in project and i have any commands for servos in each line in RTB.
I send the command for servo from lines in RTB. I need highlight(underline, bold,...whatever) line in RTB from which i send a command for servo.

For example:
This is lines from my RTB, and now i send command for servo from line 5.

1 1200

2 1400

3 1100

4 1300

**5 1880**

6 1400

7 1660

How can i do this in VS in c #?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Did you try something? Have you looked at the methods Select and GetFirstCharIndexFromLine ?

Comment: You shouldn't use a user interface element to store the data. Instead, you should have a variable, such as a list, to store the data and then have some way of transforming that data to a UI element. It makes things simpler in the end.

Answer (score 2):

If every line of your RTB Text begins with a number and a space you can try this:

```
string[] textBoxLines = richTextBox1.Lines;
for (int i = 0; i < textBoxLines.Length; i++)
{
    string line = textBoxLines[i];
    if (line.StartsWith("3 ")) // define the line number which the commands occurred
    {
        richTextBox1.SelectionStart = richTextBox1.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(i);
        richTextBox1.SelectionLength = line.Length;
        richTextBox1.SelectionFont  = new Font(richTextBox1.SelectionFont, FontStyle.Bold);
    }
}
// clear the selection
richTextBox1.SelectionLength = 0;
```

Comment: This is perfect for me. I change font style to color and this is ok.
Thank you very much!

Comment: No problem. Glad I helped.